# Why isn't this PHP-script sending the email?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a contact form on a web page to work after the web host stopped supporting the PHP-version it was built for. For some reason I can't get the email to send and I can't for the life of me figure out whats wrong with the code!

Using Chrome to monitor the network traffic I get the error message that is added to the block below.

`{success: false, error: "Kunde inte skicka e-postmeddelande"}`
("Unable to send email")

Here is the block that send the email:

```
$to = $form['email']['to'];
    $subject = $form['subject'];
    $message = get_email_body($subject, $form['heading'], $form['fields'], $form['resources']);
    $headers = get_email_headers($to, $form_email); 

    $sent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if(!$sent)
        die(get_form_error_response($form['resources']['failed_to_send_email']));

    $success_data = array(
        'redirect' => $form['success_redirect']
    );
```

Since I can't find any errors in the code I'm stuck. If anyone can see anything I can't, or maybe point me to where to look next I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: remove the **@** in `@mail(` because it prevents showing any `errors/warnings`.

Comment: I removed it. The browser is still just saying "Server encountered an error", and looking at network traffic it's the same as before.

Comment: Are you sure your `get_email_body()` or `get_email_headers()` return the correct data in the correct format? You need to post that as well or we won't have a clue what you're actually passing in to the mail-function.

Comment: _"The browser is still just saying "Server encountered an error","_ - What do you mean by "still"? This is the first time you've mentioned that error message. Check the web servers error log and check if it has some more info.

Comment: Okey I found the issue was with our email-provider. It's solved. thanks for all your help!